# Datatable columns expression

Tags: c#, datatable

I am working with an application where user can multiply quantity and price and the results appear in third column using column expression
The code i used is showed under this :

```
       DataTable dt = new DataTable("dtList");
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();//Created a new DataTable


        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        dc.ColumnName = "Price";


      DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn();
        dc1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        dc1.ColumnName = "qty"; 

          DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn();
        dc2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        dc2.ColumnName = "Total";
        dc2.Expression = "Price * qty";

       dataTable.Columns.Add(dc);//Add them to the DataTable
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dc2);

       object sumObject;
        sumObject = dt.Compute("Sum(Total)", "");

    I used this code to sum column Total, and show the result in a Text Box, but it's showing an error like this: "Cannot find column [Total]".
```

My question is what can i change, to make this code work, also sum automatically every time  when the user change qty.
Sorry for my English and mistakes at my code I am new to WPF

Comment: your code seems fine according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-expression-columns

Comment: You might want to use `typeof(System.Decimal)` instead of `GetType("System.Decimal")`.

Comment: No way that is working code.  dc2, dc4 and dc6 are not defined.

Comment: *Dai still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a fast check to your code I can see one thing.You define a DataTable called dt and then you try to compute the column "dt.Total" but you have never defined a column in you dt.

Try changing your:

sumObject = dt.Compute("Sum(Total)", "");

to

sumObject = dataTable.Compute("Sum(Total)", "");

Edit:  By the way, if you do this:

```
dataTable = new DataTable();//Created a new DataTable


        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        dc.ColumnName = "Price";


        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn();
        dc1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        dc1.ColumnName = "qty";

        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn();
        dc2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        dc2.ColumnName = "Total";
        dc2.DefaultValue = 5;
        dc2.Expression = "Price * qty";

        dataTable.Columns.Add(dc);//Add them to the DataTable
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dc2);
```

Your third column already has the value "price * qty". 
If you want to show the sum of all your dc Total column just use:

```
            object sumObject = dataTable.Compute("Sum(Total)", "");
```

And then

```
yourTextbox.Text = sumObject.ToString();
```

Comment: jk93 thanks man. I have also a question. How can i update the textbox result every time the user change the quantity

Comment: publish another question because i cant put any code here.

Comment: Thanks again, i founded the way to do this